# Woocommerce recent products not showing in 4 columns

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have been setup with this template on WordPress. How do I go about changing the columns to 4 on this visual composer element even though it is already set to 4?

The url is: 24konline.com

You will see the issue I am talking about on the home page.